# IOS push notification not receiving from c#

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have checked so many links and I have tried sandbox has host name, also installed .p12 file in local computer. and before this code is working perfectly. and also how to check what is response from apple when send push notification. code perfectly process as expected but push notification not receiving.

```
try
{
    int port = 2195;
   
    String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
    
    //String certificatePath = "";
    String certificatePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/pushcert.pem");
    X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), "");
    X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
    SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
    try
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)32);

         



        var aps1 = new
        {
            alert = Subject,
            messageId = "test",
            type = type,
            badge = 1,
            sound = "default"
        };
        var aps = new
        {
            aps = aps1
        };



        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aps);

        writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(deviceID.ToUpper()));
        String payload = json; 
        writer.Write((byte)0);
        writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);

      

        byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        writer.Write(b1);
        writer.Flush();
        byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
        sslStream.Write(array);
        sslStream.Flush();
        client.Close();

    }
    catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
    {
        saveException(ex.Message, "Failed", "MobileAPI/SendMessage");
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        saveException(e.Message, "Failed", "MobileAPI/SendMessage");
        client.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    saveException(e.Message, "Failed", "MobileAPI/SendMessage");
}
```

Comment: _"and before this code is working perfectly."_ - "before" what? If you had a working version and now with some changeset it doesn't then those changes probably broke the code. What were the changes?

Comment: I have nothing changed

Comment: I am facing the same problem. All of a sudden iOS notification stopped working. Neither PHP backend code nor iOS app code was changed. I was hoping to get some answer to this question but no luck.